# R Shiny landing page

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps, shinyjs

I am new to Shiny and trying to run the sample App linked below.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/career-pathfinder.html

https://github.com/georgemirandajr/career-pathfinder

But I am getting a massive black box on the landing page - was this intentional?
If not, where in the code is the relevant section for this landing page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [app](https://geom.shinyapps.io/careerpathfinder-beta/?_ga=2.185457641.1558388723.1593869902-1939714255.1576014464) seems to be working, but it downloads a very big image for the background.

The title 'CAREER PATHFINDER' is black on a black background as long as the background image is not yet downloaded, so you don't see it, but if you maintain mouse click on the black box and move the mouse (as one would do for a select), you'll see the title appear.

The code is [here](https://github.com/georgemirandajr/career-pathfinder)

The background image is called by following section in the UI :

```
fluidRow(
    HTML(
        "
        <section class='banner'>
        <h2 class='parallax'>CAREER PATHFINDER</h2>
        <p class='parallax_description'>A career path pinpoints your next job, the job
        after that, and beyond.</p>
        </section>
        "
    )
)
```

The `css` associated to it is `/www/paper.css` which calls :

```
background-image: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/297755/pexels-photo-297755.jpeg');
```

for the `parallax` section

Comment: Thanks for this - very helpful. Do you know where in the code I can find this background image?

Comment: I didn't find background image either :(

Comment: found background image ;-), if this is ok please accept the answer.

Comment: @Joseph, if this answered your question, could you accept the answer?